# End short line in fully-justified text

Tags: line-breaking, justification

I want to end a line in justified text without having the line streched.
Basically I want \linbreak to justify the one line it ends left.

For this I dont want to use setparsizes (or similar) since I still want be able to use \par.

Thank you

Comment: `\\ `  is the standard command for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use `\\` or `\newline` and none of it will hinder the use of `\par`

**Using `\\`**

```
This is a line that I want to break the line after.\\ This is the next line
```

or

```
This is a line that I want to break the line after.\\
This is the next line
```

**Using `\newline`**

```
This is a line that I want to break the line after.\newline This is the next line
```

or

```
This is a line that I want to break the line after.\newline
This is the next line
```

Comment: using a blank line is very different to using `\\ ` the question I think asks for `\\ `  a line break not a new paragraph.

Comment: I mentioned at the end that skipping a line will render your next line like a paragraph. But I'll edit the answer for `\\ ` and `\newline`, cheers :-)

Comment: yes but it's the only code block you show and you don't say that the effects of  `You can use \\, \newline, or you can skip a line in the editor.` are different, so it ends up being misleading (even though everything you do say is true:-)

Comment: Somehow I thought that \newline was bad practice. But you are totally right, sorry for the dump question.